# How to break apart Hstore keys and values into separate columns in postgres

Tags: postgresql, tags, openstreetmap, hstore

I have an osm table with all the tags found in the hstore column named tags.

I want to write a query that will return a table with the all the columns of the table and additional columns for each tag having each key as the column name and the value under it. How do I go about that?

So my input will be:

```
Item_id | tags |
----------+-------+
1614     | apple=2,bees=150|
1938     | apple=1,bees=50  |
1983     | apple=1,bees=50  |
1322     | apple=1,bees=100|
```

output will be of the script

```
item_id | apple |  bees 
---------+-------+------
   1614  |   2   |  150
   1938  |   1   |  50
   1983  |   1   |  50
   1322  |   1   |  100
```

taking into account that each row have a varied amount of tags and i dont know what are the counts and what are the keys attached to each column so how do I go about so for example

```
     Item_id | tags |
    ----------+-------+
    1614     | apple=2,bees=150,green=345|
    1938     | apple=1,bees=50  |
    1983     | apple=1,bees=50  |
    1322     | apple=1,bees=100,red=346|
```

output will be:

```
  item_id | apple |  bees |  green | red|
    ---------+-------+----+--------+----+
       1614  |   2   |  150 |345| NULL|
       1938  |   1   |  50  |NULL| NULL|
       1983  |   1   |  50  |NULL| NULL|
       1322  |   1   |  100 |NULL| 346|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that accepts a table name, and a list of keys. It then creates the new table and columns. It demonstrates how to do dynamic commands within the function. The SELECT at the end shows how to extract your keys. Populating the table can be done by looping through the rows of your existing table after creating your columns. There is almost certainly a more elegant/efficient way to do all of this :)

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION explode_hstore(tname text, keys TEXT[]) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    k TEXT;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Creating table=%', tname;
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || tname || ' ()';
    FOREACH k IN ARRAY keys
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Adding column for key=%', k;
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || tname || ' ADD COLUMN ' || k || ' TEXT';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

To run the function:

`SELECT explode_hstore('exploded_hstore', 
    (select array_agg(x.keys) FROM (SELECT skeys("data") AS keys 
     FROM hstoretest GROUP BY keys) x))`

Comment: I have to mention that this is probably not a good idea. There are over 50,000 unique tags in the OSM data. Most apps will predefine a subset and use columns for them and hstore for the rest. That subset could be the most common tags, or domain related (roads for example). Also bear in mind that Postgres has a limit of 250-16000 columns (depending on the type).