# Explode hstore into new columns within row

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, hstore

I have the following table in PostgreSQL. The `hstore` extension is activated.

| osm_id | hstore_column |
| --- | --- |
| 172544 | "kerb"=>"lowered", "highway"=>"crossing", "crossing"=>"marked", "crossing_ref"=>"zebra", "tactile_paving"=>"yes", "crossing_island"=>"yes", "crossing_markings"=>"zebra" |
| 172548 | "bus"=>"yes", "name"=>"Londoner Straße", "ref_BVG"=>"103010", "website"=>"https_//qr.bvg.de/h103010", "public_transport"=>"stop_position" |
| 458330 | "ref"=>"7", "name"=>"Kaiserdamm", "highway"=>"motorway_junction", "destination"=>"Kaiserdamm" |

I want to explode the `hstore_column` into columns for each key.

Table header should turn into

| osm_id | kerb | highway | crossing | crossing_ref | tactile | crossing_island | crossing_markings | bus | name | ref_BVG | website | public_transport | ref | destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 172544 | lowered | crossing | marked | zebra | yes | yes | zebra |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

This [related answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94717/dynamically-convert-hstore-keys-into-columns-for-an-unknown-set-of-keys/123006#123006) requires that keys are known.
The issue is that the set of keys is unknown beforehand.

In this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602199/how-to-break-apart-hstore-keys-and-values-into-separate-columns-in-postgres) the given function has problems with key words appearing as tags in the hstore column.

Is there a way to dynamically explode hstore keys into single columns within the same table? Only solution I know is in Python, but in-database-processing is more suitable.

Comment: Now you know why ad hoc nested data is an issue, it just pushes the structure determination into the future. Then when you get to the future you have a mess to unravel. The answer is no there is not a way to do what you want in SQL.

Comment: "*in-database-processing is more suitable*" - why?

Comment: An actual fiddle to work with, and (always!) your version of Postgres would make this a lot easier to answer.

Comment: @Bergi I want to import large datasets into tables. The result of the aimed workflow could be persisted in a materialized view.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue is that the set of keys is unknown beforehand.

So there is no solution with a single statement (single round trip to the server). We need a **two-step flow**. Like:

**Step 1:** determine the set of keys, and create a temporary type from it dynamically. (There are various other ways to channel the gathered information, this just seems most convenient):

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   DROP TYPE IF EXISTS pg_temp.osm_exploded;
   
   EXECUTE (
   SELECT format('CREATE TYPE pg_temp.osm_exploded AS (%s)'
               , string_agg(quote_ident(key) || ' text', ', '))
   FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT key
      FROM   tbl, skeys(hstore_column) key
      ORDER  BY key
      ) sub
   );
END   
$do$;
```

Now the target structure is known, and the rest is easy.

The "trick" with a temporary type is similar to the one with a temporary function. ([Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)'s improvement.) See:

- [How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990622/how-to-create-a-temporary-function-in-postgresql)

Be aware that Postgres allows a [maximum of 1600 columns per table row](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/limits.html) (or less if some other limit is exceeded). The same limit applies to the number of columns in composite types.

**Step 2:** Simple query with [`populate_record()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#id-1.11.7.28.6.4.2.2.22.1.1.1):

```sql
SELECT t.osm_id, o.*
FROM   tbl t, populate_record(null::pg_temp.osm_exploded, t.hstore_column) o;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kg671VfY)

The implicit `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` is safe because `populate_record()` always returns a row. (A set-returning function returning "no row" would eliminate the result row, and you might want to use `LEFT JOIN ... ON true`.)

Related answer with alternative, working solutions, one spelling out all keys in the `SELECT` list, one using `crosstab()` from the additional module `tablefunc`:

- [Dynamically convert hstore keys into columns for an unknown set of keys](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/123006/3684)

Comment: Why create a table when all you need is a composite type?

Comment: @Bergi: Because we can create a **temporary** table, but there is no `CREATE TEMP TYPE`.

Comment: Ah. I wonder if `CREATE TYPE pg_temp.osm_exploded` would work though, similar to the [temp function trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4990622/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi: That works, too. Actually a brilliant idea!

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you for your Answer. I adapted your code from Step 1 with my own example in line 11  to "FROM public.all_point, skeys(all_tags) key".  The result seems to be fine because the key structure is written in the output. The adaption of Step 2 is: "SELECT t.osm_id, o.*
FROM public.all_point t, populate_record(null::pg_temp.osm_exploded, t.all_tags) o;" PostgreSQL Error Message is "ERROR:  schema "pg_temp" does not exist
LINE 2: FROM public.all_point t, populate_record(null::pg_temp.osm_e...". Is there something missing?

Comment: @michaber When using temporary objects, you have to stay within the same session. Else, create a permanent object.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I stayed in the same session. I'm not that familiar to convert your example into something persistent.

Comment: @michaber: Your adaptation seems fine, but you only get `ERROR:  schema "pg_temp" does not exist` if no temp object has been created yet. Either you didn't complete step 1 or you didn't stay within the same session. Both cannot be true.